# render components depending on the v-if

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a b-dropdown-item of Bootstrap, where I call the same view and redirect the selection of the element that must load a component in the view or another. On the other hand I'm using the V-directive if in the view and the contents of the drop-down menu id show me one component or another.
Can someone help me do this?
thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, it is not clear what you are asking. Can you rephrase the question and see if it works better?

Answer (score 0):

Create some state for the current selected option `data: { selectedOption: "" }`

Bind it to your select field. `<select v-model="selectedOption">... your options here <select>`

Now you can create a computed property to resolve your component.
(This example works if you have the following components: A and B)

```
computed: { 
   resolveComponent(){ 
      if(this.selectedOption === 'a')
         return A;
      else if(this.selectedOption === 'b')
         return B;
   } 
}
```

Now you can bind this dynamic component to a component element:

`<component :is="resolveComponent"></component>`